# Is there a way to limit the number of CPU Cores used for physics baking?

Tags: physics, baking, performance, hardware

Is there a way (in Blender) to limit the number of CPU Cores used for physics baking, like you can with rendering?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a straight forward answer for this, it will depend on what simulation you want to bake and what OS you are using.

To use multiple cpus, some parts of blender use [openmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) and others use [pthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).

For simulations using openMP, setting the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` [environment variable](http://www.bgu.ac.il/intel_fortran_docs/compiler_f/main_for/mergedProjects/optaps_for/common/optaps_par_var.htm) should limit the cpus used.

For simulations using pthreads, adjusting system limits should be able to limit the cpus or cpu time used. The way to do this varies between most operating systems, for linux there are [`/proc/...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8849114/2684771) settings or the bash builtin `ulimit` command.

Another approach available on most *nix systems is the `nice` and `renice` commands to adjust the cpu priority so that other procs are given cpu time before blender.

Comment: On Windows you can press CTRL+SHIFT+ESC, find blender process in *Details* tab, right-click and choose *Affinity*. I think those settings reset every time, but you can use a program like WinAFC to automate changing affinity.